# Why are cousins not mentioned in relation to Leviticus 18:6?

Tags: leviticus, torah

> Leviticus 18:6 ‘None of you shall approach anyone who is near of kin to him, to uncover his nakedness: I am the Lord. (NKJV)

Is sexual intercourse between cousins included on this passage? If it is, why it isn't mentioned the word cousin?

Comment: *Why isn't the word cousin mentioned ?* - Probably because the Bible wasn't written in English.

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! Make sure you take our Tour (lower left). Thanks

Comment: It is because cousins are permitted to marry each other. It is not just any kin that is prohibited from engaging in a sexual relationship, only the specific relatives enumerated in that chapter.

Answer (score 1):

What is being forbidden in this passage, Leviticus 18:6-18, is the inappropriate approach to one who is 'any relation of his flesh' [Young's Literal]. One's own flesh is produced by a marriage union. Within the compass of that union, it is wickedly inappropriate to approach such a relation with the intention of even uncovering that flesh which was a produce of the same marriage union as oneself.

If the commandment is received and obeyed, then it is impossible that any misconduct would occur as the act would be prevented. The approach, with the intention, is forbidden.

In the passage, Jehovah forbids such an approach to an uncle's wife or to an aunt. Such are of the same marriage union, since they are the siblings of a parent or married to such a sibling.

But a cousin is further removed, being of a successive generation, and at a further remove from one's own parent.